# Where can I find compass's source files in Windows?

Tags: javascript, sass, gruntjs, compass-sass

I want to be able to use a very few select the `compass` mixin's but don't want to have to use `compass` like this, i.e use compass at all:

```
 @import "compass";
 @import "compass/reset";
 @import "compass/css3";
```

So, are the mixin's installed somewhere on my computer? I have look in places similar to and including this path:

```
 C:\Ruby200-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\compass-0.12.2\examples\css3\src
```

Maybe I am thinking about this in the incorrect way?

Comment: What's wrong with just using Compass?  You *can* just import specific files that contain the mixins you want.

Comment: Sadly it takes 5s to compile, I'm rather happy just using susy without compass if its taking that much longer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can actually view the source files once the are installed. Since Compass is open source, you can view everything on Github: https://github.com/Compass/compass/tree/stable/core/stylesheets/compass

For example, here is a mixin from `css3/border-radius`:

```
@mixin border-corner-radius($vert, $horz, $radius: $default-border-radius) {
  @include with-each-prefix(border-radius, $border-radius-threshold) {
    @if $current-prefix == -moz {
      // Support for mozilla's syntax for specifying a corner
      @include prefix-prop("border-radius-#{$vert}#{$horz}", $radius);
    } @else {
      // Official syntax for everyone else
      @include prefix-prop("border-#{$vert}-#{$horz}-radius", $radius);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If only I knew that they were so complex :) it seems its not just simple `sass` :D

Comment: That's because it's not.  It uses data from caniuse.com to determine whether or not it needs to add prefixes.